# Tabular parameters in Thucydides+Jbehave

Tags: java, jbehave, thucydides

I have the following code:

```
When searching by Login Name <loginName>  as a filter
Then users only with <loginName> are displayed

Examples:
|<loginName>|
|admin|
|admin2|
|admin3|
```

And the following methods mapped to it.

```
@When("searching by Login Name $loginName as a filter")
public void searchingBySpecifiedLoginNameAsAFilter(String loginName)
{
   ...
}

@Then("users only with $loginName are displayed")
public void usersOnlyWithSpecifiedLoginNameAreDisplayed(String loginName)
{
    ...
}
```

My problem is that when i run the tests , instead of the desired parameters the functions use ">loginName>" string ,eventhough there is a scenario for each example,and i see that it's mapping them (Ex. >loginName> = admin ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is :

```
When searching by Login Name '<loginName>' as a filter
Then users only with '<loginName>' are displayed

Examples:
|loginName|
|admin|
|admin2|
|admin3|

  @When("searching by Login Name '<loginName>' as a filter")
   public void searchingBySpecifiedLoginNameAsAFilter(String loginName)
{
    ...

}
```